Calculating the Divergence of a Function on Unit Ball
I am reading the paper "A remark on the map $\frac{x}{|x|}$". In the paper, it is claimed that for any map $U\in H^1(B^n,S^{n-1})$ such that $U(x)=x$ on $S^{n-1}$,
$$\text{div} U=n-1$$
I don’t know how to show this equality. Any hints will be appreciated.

The divergence, denoted here as $\operatorname{div}$, is the divergence on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. Let $M^{n-1}$ be an oriented hypersurface in $\mathbb R^n$ with unit normal $\nu$ and $F:M \to \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ (not necessarily tangential) vector field. Then the divergence of $F$ on $M$ is given by $$\operatorname{div}^M F(x) = \operatorname{div}^{\mathbb R^n} \tilde F(x)- \nu^T(x) D^{\mathbb R^n} \tilde F(x) \nu(x) \qquad \text{for all } x\in M$$ where $\tilde F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is any $C^1$ extension of $F$ to $\mathbb R^n$. The important thing to emphasise here is that this definition is independent of the choice of extension $\tilde F$.
In this case, $M=\mathbb S^{n-1}$, $U:B^n \to \mathbb S^{n-1}$ is such that $U(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb S^{n-1}$. An extension of $U$ is then $\tilde U: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ given by $\tilde U(x)=x$. Since, in this case, $\nu(x)=x$, we have \begin{align*}
\operatorname{div} U(x)=\operatorname{div}^{\mathbb S^{n-1}} U (x) &= \operatorname{div}^{\mathbb R^n} \tilde U(x)- \nu^T(x) D^{\mathbb R^n} \tilde U(x) \nu(x)\\
&=\operatorname{div}^{\mathbb R^n} x- x^T (D^{\mathbb R^n}  x )x\\
&=n-\vert x \vert^2\\
&=n-1
\end{align*} since $\vert x \vert =1$.

I see. May you give me a reference for that formula of divergence?

Yep. A geometric measure theory reference is in chapter 10 of ‘Minimal Surfaces and Functions of Bounded Variation’ by Guisti. An extrinsic geometry reference is Appendix A of ‘Regularity Theory for Mean Curvature Flow’ by Ecker.

If you know the definition of divergence on a Riemannian manifold you can also unpack this definition via the Gauss-Codazzi equations. Also, see Chapter 2.3 in ‘Elliptic partial differential equations from an elementary viewpoint’ by Dipierro and Valdinoci
